# Does the ladder really fit inside the barn?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, inertial-frames, observers

Does the [ladder really fit inside the barn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ladder_paradox)?

If we could take a photo, would we see the ladder inside the barn?

Comment: Can you give more information on the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it does.

But taking a photo is more complicated than you think because you have to allow for the time the light from the two ends of the ladder take to reach your camera. If you were to photograph a fast moving object you'd find the picture would not show the object shortened. Instead it would be rotated. This is known as [Terrell rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terrell_rotation).

However you could check the ladder fits a different way. Suppose you and your friend synchronise your watches and then stand at each end of the barn and record the exact time the end of ladder is level with the end of barn. When you compare your times you'd find they are the same i.e. the whole ladder was inside the barn at the time you recorded.